# Javascript doesnt contact php page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, rating

im quite new to php and javascript but still trying to get my webpage to work.
Im trying to add a 5-star-voting-system to the page which will contact my database and update accordingly. 
As you might have noticed my code grammar isnt perfect either.

```
<div class="first"  onmouseover="starmove('-32px')" onmouseout="starnormal()" onclick="rate('harrys','1')">
```

this is the div that "contacts" the javascript

```
function rate(id,ratings){
var i=id;
var r=ratings;
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
   { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

this is the javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Namnlös 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect("host", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$itemid = ($_GET["id"]);
$rating = ($_GET["rating"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ('$itemid','$rating')";
mysql_query($query);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my rating.php file (note: the values in mysql_connect is right on actual page, even if not defined here.)

if I just open my php file there will be a row added to mysql so i know its connected properly.

Comment: It may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: What exactly is not working? Give us the problem and we will help

Comment: When I press the div called "first" nothing happens. Thats the problem, sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing the values to rating.php as GET but you are fetching it as POST

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
```

Here, even if you give the method as POST, `?id="+i+"&rating="+r` means that id and rating is being passed as GET.

So you cannot access them as

```
$itemid = ($_POST["id"]);
$rating = ($_POST["rating"]);
```

You will need to change that to:

```
$itemid = ($_GET["id"]);
$rating = ($_GET["rating"]);
```

Also change your query to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ('".$itemid."','".$rating."')";
```

EDIT:

I have updated the Javascript code here. Try this:

```
<script>
function rate(id,ratings)
{
    var i=id;
    var r=ratings;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    { 
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Changes:
 1. There were two braces after:

```
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   }
```

The second brace effectively closed the `rate()` function, so the code after that wasnt doing what it was expected to. So I moved that brace to the end of the code, to wrap the function.

1. The `onreadystatechange` function is called AFTER data has been sent to the server in order to track, what is going on with the request. In your code, you were sending the request INSIDE the onreadystatechange, which would never execute, since the request would never get sent..

I changed

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
         xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
         xmlhttp.send();
       }
```

into a simple POST call:

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
 xmlhttp.send();
```

I hope this explains everything :)

Comment: GET and POST have been messing with me all day, but thanks for pointing that out. Even when these things have been changed, no result is shown in the database.

Comment: @EricWennerberg: I have also updated the query string you are running, please check my answer once more, as it is easy to post code snippets there than in comment section. Let me know if that helped.

Comment: @EricWennerberg: In my query I had accidentally referred to `$itemid` as `$id`. That might have caused the issue. I have updated the answer once again *phew*. Check if that helps :)

Comment: I noticed that before, and had already changed it before saying it didnt work. Im going crazyyyy. :p

Comment: Ok, so the javascript code had some issues. I have updated it in the EDIT section of my answer. Can you try that? :D

That should work or else I am going to chew through my hat!! >:)

Comment: Im afraid your hat gotta go then....
This seems hopeless at the moment. I might have to rewrite it all and use jQuery as suggested instead of just normal javascript.

Comment: I got the whole thing running in my machine, which is why I bet my hat! :P

*Sigh* well..sorry I couldnt help you with it. Works in my box though.. Anyways, better luck with jQuery!

Comment: I think you should let you hat live though, just tested it again after restarting browser. It works, but only the rating value, not the id. EDIT: If i change the input of id in the div, rate('5','1') it works perfect, but when the 5 is a word or name, as it should be a "0" is added in the database.

Comment: Just realised that was caused by the database being set as INT and not text. Everything works properly now thanks to you. :)

Comment: Do you mind explaining what you changed and why? So your hat can live forever! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try jQuery for XHTTP Calls. That way, you are sure that all browsers are supported with your code.

Add this to your head section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Then use this code to make the call to the PHP page:

```
var i = id;
var r = ratings;
$.get("http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r);
```

I also noticed  you did put "sds" in the "id" field in your query. The "id" field should be an integer. If it is an integer already, that's your problem. Also change $_POST to $_GET. Fixed version:

```
$itemid = ($_GET["id"]);
$rating = ($_GET["rating"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ($itemid,'$rating')";
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. I totally agree with you that using something like jQuery is a good idea, but "Use jQuery" is not really an answer to the question "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: Yeah, only the last part is answering his question. You're right. I am just trying to help a bit more. ;)

Comment: Tried adding the script in head section, and changing the javascript, but still no success.

Comment: Did you change the $_POST to $_GET in your script?

Answer (score 0):

Please use jQuery to handle ajax requests. jQuery works cross browser and you can be sure it works.

Also:

```
$itemid = ($_POST["id"]);
$rating = ($_POST["rating"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ('sds','$rating')";
```

Is insecure

```
$itemid = intval($_POST["id"]);
$rating = intval($_POST["rating"]);
$query = "INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ('sds','$rating')";
```

is a lot better

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. I totally agree with you that using something like jQuery is a good idea, but "Use jQuery" is not really an answer to the question "Why doesn't this work?"

Answer (score 0):

First, use relative instead of absolute links if the php file you're trying to request is in the same site:

```
// Absolute link
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://------/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);

// Relative link
xmlhttp.open("POST","rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
```

Then, you're trying to send and retrieve the info via `POST`, but you're sending the info in a query string (`GET`):

JS:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);
```

PHP:

```
$itemid = $_GET["id"];
$rating = $_GET["rating"];
```

Finally, before you insert, use mysql_real_escape_string() or mysqli_real_escape_string(), depending on the MySQL library you're using, to prevent SQL injection in the database and compromise your site:

```
$itemid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
$rating = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["rating"]);
$query = 'INSERT INTO ratings(id,rating) VALUES ('.$itemid.','.$rating.')';
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: The page where the javascript is being executed is not in same folder, so absolute link is necessary. Havnt given much thought to safety yet, since I cant even get the function to work, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: assuming your php file in the folder 'path-to-www-root/request' and your js file in the folder 'path-to-www-root/js' and assuming you' calling js from the level 'path-to-www-root', you should call the php like this:
`xmlhttp.open("GET","request/rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);`

Comment: my jsfile is in folder while my php is not.
path-to-root/folder/js
path-to-root/rating.php

Comment: if the html that calls the js, is in the same level, you should call the php like this:
`xmlhttp.open("GET","../rating.php?id="+i+"&rating="+r,true);`